# PHP array sorting by scored results from database

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that I'm simply trying to order by a `score` key that contains the value that I'm trying to sort by. The desired results would change the order of the array below to display the index in the following order: `[0]`, `[2]`, `[1]`.

I'm looping through the results which are pulled from a database. I'm creating a key named `score` and then pushing the `$row2` array in to a separate array because if I use `mysql_data_seek` it gets rid of the `score` key.

Also it's creating an unwanted key `score` at the bottom.

How can I best clean this up and make sure the results are ordered high to low as desired?

```
$my_array = array();

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
 //score determined here
 //$row2['score'] = ...more math, variable is numeric, not a string
 array_push($array_page,$row2);
}
```

Current undesired results...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [score] => 7
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [score] => 4
        )
    [score] => 
)
```

Desired results...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [score] => 7
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [score] => 4
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 2
        )
)
```

Comment: Use `order by score` in your query.

Comment: I'm not processing the score in the SQL query. >__>

Comment: ... But you're getting the score using a SQL query, right? Let the database do all the work for you.

Comment: No, this is all processed by PHP. Even if I could do this with MySQL  I'll be migrating away from MySQL to PostgreSQL to avoid dealing with Oracle's politics so the last thing I want to do is create overly complex SQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function scoreSort($a, $b){
  if($a['score'] == $b['score']) return 0;
  return $a['score'] > $b['score'] ? -1 : 1;
}
usort(&$myArray, 'scoreSort');
```

on php>5.3 you can use inline-functoins:

```
usort(&$myArray, function($a,$b){ /* ... */ });
```

Comment: to maintain the KEYS while sorting, please use "uksort"

Comment: This looks ALMOST good enough for me to accept only that it sorted the opposite way with the heaviest scores at the bottom instead of at the top where I need them. I could reverse the array though is there a simpler modification to your function that I could use please? I tried the more obvious part of changing the minus operator to plus though that didn't work.

Comment: changed ;)
just replace the "<" with ">" :D